# Javascript code assist in maven project Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, maven

Please let me know how can we get javascript code assist in eclipse for maven project.
We are working on cq5 project.

I am looking for maven project for cq5 in which we will have js files under etc/designs but when we try to edit in eclipse not getting javascrpt code assist and no way to change the perspective.
Please let us know if we are missing anything..

Comment: Switch to Intellij IDEA, It has very good support to Java and all front end technologies

Comment: I have updated the question looking for javascript code assist in cq5 project under etc/designs

Comment: Good to switch on Backets. LightWeight IDE